# How to rearrange letters from a word from a list that you have made?

Tags: python

How do you rearrange the letters in a word(the word is in a list.) I'm trying to make a program where I make a list and randomly pick a word from the list, then I have to re arrange the word's letters and make a list including those letters then I have to tell the user the theme of the first list and show them the scrambled word and then they have to guess the word based on the theme I gave them and the letters they have.This is the code I have so far I have no problem with anything except the rearranging the letters and making a list for them:

```
import random
mysports= ["swimming" , "basketball" , "soccer" , "cross country" , "football" , "cross-country skiing"]
a = (random.choice(mysports)) 
if a == mysports[0]:
  #code that is supposed to re arrange the letters
elif a == mysports[1]:
  #code that is supposed to re arrange the letters
elif a == mysports[2]:
  #code that is supposed to re arrange the letters
elif a == mysports[3]:
  #code that is supposed to re arrange the letters
elif a == mysports[4]:
  #code that is supposed to re arrange the letters
elif a == mysports[5]:
  #code that is supposed to re arrange the letters
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.shuffle` to randomly rearrange a list:

```
import random
word = list('abracadabra')
random.shuffle(word)
```

Note that `shuffle` changes a list in-place. It does *not* return a modified copy of the list; it changes the actual list passed.

Comment: I did and it says this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 23, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment.

Comment: @TheCoder360 that might be because you typed `word = 'whatever'` instead of `word = list('whatever')`. Don't forget to call `list`.